# Dynamic positioning of html elements - Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, css

During the work on my Asp.net project I came across the following problem:

I have an html `<span>` located on html `<table>` that located in an `<asp:Panel>`, and I want that the position of the `<span>` in the table will be according its text.

Explanation:

[image]

The text shown in the yellow rectangle is the text of the `<span>` and the long red rectangle is the table that contains the `<span>`.

The text of the `<span>` is changed by a button click, like in the following picture:

[image]

As we can see in the picture, the text on the `<span>` is changed, and now the text is longer than before, so I want the `<span>` to move right instead of became larger to the left direction, I mean: I want that when the text on the span is long then the `<span>` will move to the right.

I know, in Windows Forms U can make something like that in less than a second, but in HTML and CSS, I can burn hours on the computer and still there is no solution.

My HTML / CSS code:

```
<form id="mainForm" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="main" runat="server" CssClass="main-style"> 
        <table id="details" style="position: relative; width: 95vw; height: 26px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 30px">
            <tr> 
                <td style="border: solid red 1px;">
                    <span id="userNameLabel" runat="server" style="color: powderblue;" class="username-label-style">XXXXX</span>
                </td> 
            </tr>
        </table>
        <style>           
        THE PANEL STYLE HERE - NOT IMPORTANT NOW.
        .username-label-style { 
            background: Transparent;                
            top: 0px;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 0;
            width: 100px;
            height: 26px;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: large;
        }
        </style>
    </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

I tried by using the `margin-right` property, but nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for `text-align`?

Comment: no, the text is aligned to the left and that's okay. i want to make the <span> aligned to the left, i mean: the space in the right side will always be the same, no matter what the length of the text is.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to `text-align: right;`

Comment: What exactly would you do in Windows Forms, then? There may be some HTML equivalent. Bear in mind that tables in HTML don't, by default, have fixed widths for columns. So if you make the content of the column wider then it will stretch that column wider, assuming there's enough space in the table's container. Exactly how it appears will depend on the content of the other columns, the width rules of the container element(s) and potentially the width of the browser window. It's not clear whether you're complaining about the **text** moving, or the **column** moving.